# How can Nginx use try_files only if file exists?

Tags: symfony, nginx

I have fully worked example of virtual host for a project on `Symfony` from ()[].

There is a code:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name localhost www.localhost;
    root /vagrant/web;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        #internal;
    }
}
```

But I want to improve it a bit for me. How can I load `maintenance.html` by default instead of `app_dev.php`?

P.S. I need a behaviour like with `try_files $uri /maintenance.html$is_args$args;` instead of `try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;`, but **ONLY** if `maintenance.html` exists

Comment: I’d use `if` for that.

Comment: @Smar Thanks, but I solved it with `try_files $uri /maintenance.html$is_args$args /app_dev.php$is_args$args;` and it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from [here](https://lincolnloop.com/blog/pro-tip-redirecting-custom-nginx-maintenance-page/) with bit of comments

```
location / { #can be any location or even in server
    if (-f $document_root/maintenance.html) {
        return 503;     #503 for search engines
    }
    ... # the rest of your config goes here
}

error_page 503 @maintenance;
location @maintenance {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /maintenance.html break;
}
```

Comment: It's intersting, but broke all my styles, scripts and images (503 status code).

Comment: I my example it written for / so it replaces any request for any files except other locations. So it replaces styles and scripts to 503 too

Comment: Thanks! I used it only for `app.php` (`prod` environment) and it work perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with:

```
try_files $uri /maintenance.html$is_args$args /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
```

Comment: @Smar I can't, StackOverflow say I could accept in 2 days :)

Comment: Whoops, I didn’t know ^^